# My bot program accepts user input and then instead of replying, does nothing

Tags: java

I created a bot and used a snippet of code I invented called "simplify" to dramatically shorten java commands.

Only problem is, the bot program I made with it doesn't work. It's supposed to search the user input for keywords and reply accordingly, but all it really does is accept user input and then turn off. What did I do wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class bot{
        //"simplify" and "bot" created by @genisome, All rights reserved.
    System.out.println(in);

}



public static void print(String in){

System.out.println(in);

}



public static void print(double in){

System.out.println(in);

}



public static void print(long in){

System.out.println(in);

}



public static void print(boolean in){

System.out.println(in);

}



public static void print(float in){

System.out.println(in);

}



//scan below



public static void scan(int dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.nextInt();

}



public static void scan(String dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.next();

}



public static void scan(double dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.nextDouble();

}



public static void scan(float dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.nextFloat();

}





public static void scan(boolean dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.nextBoolean();

}

public static void random(int min, int max, int dumpinto){
    Random x = new Random();
    dumpinto = x.nextInt(max) + min;
}

public static void main (String[] x){
int score;
String[] badcomputerresponse = {"that sucks, sorry", "sorry about that", "bummer", "shit", "aw, damn"};
String[] goodcomputerresponse = {"awesome.", "me too", "great", "cool", "I'm not bad myself"};
String[] goodwords = {"good", "fine", "dandy", "awesome", "cool", "swell", "great", "amazing", "ok", "okay", "well", "happy", "thrilled"};
String[] badwords = {"shitty", "terrible", "sad", "bad", "crappy", "terrible", "sucky", "up shit creek", "pathetic", "miserable", "badly", "terribly", "miserably"};
String input = "";
print("Hey there, how are you doing?");
scan(input);
for (int counter = 0; counter < goodwords.length; counter++){
    if (input.contains(goodwords[counter])){
        if (input.contains("not")){
            sadanswer(badcomputerresponse);
        }
        else{
            happyanswer(goodcomputerresponse);
    }
}
}
for (int count2 = 0; count2 < badwords.length; count2++){
    if (input.contains(badwords[count2])){
        if (input.contains("not")){
            happyanswer(goodcomputerresponse);
        }
        else{
            sadanswer(badcomputerresponse);
    }
}
}
}    
public static void sadanswer(String[] badcomputerresponse){
    int randomanswer = 0;
    random(0, badcomputerresponse.length, randomanswer);
    print(badcomputerresponse[randomanswer]);
}

public static void happyanswer(String[] goodcomputerresponse){
    int randomanswer = 0;
    random(0, goodcomputerresponse.length, randomanswer);
    print(goodcomputerresponse[randomanswer]);
}
}
```

edit: thank you people who gave me help instead of downvoting me.
To the people who downvoted me, you stink!

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: try adding more system.out.printlns throughout your program and you can narrow down where the program is stopping. An easier approach is to use the debuger. If you are using Eclipse it has a debugger called ant. If you are using Visual Studio then it also has a debuger. The debugger takes a little bit to get used to so try the first approach first to get used to debugging.

Comment: @Katianie Eclipse does have a decent debugger but I don't believe it is actually called Ant. I think you may be getting that mixed up with the build tool, Ant, which Eclipse does also support.

Comment: Yea thats true, Ant is the build tool but I think its under the same tab? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you define a bunch of `scan` methods like this:

```
public static void scan(String dumpinto){

Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

dumpinto = x.next();

}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
String input = "";
print("Hey there, how are you doing?");
scan(input);
```

That function does not do what it looks like it does. `String dumpinto` is an *input* parameter to the method. You can't write output to it. Once the method is done executing, the value that you typed in is lost. After you call `scan(input);`, the `input` variable still contains `""`. (Print it out or use a debugger to verify.)

Your `scan` method needs to return a value. Better yet, get rid of those methods altogether and just use one `Scanner` object to get input from the user.